# Help with doing face averaging with two Images

Tags: mesh

I have to do a little project. The task is to do an average face image with two face images. It is a part of face morphing.

I am little bit struggling with it. I put two images as a plane and then subdived first picture. Then I connected both images into a mesh and warped it.
After that I don't know what to do.

Left side: after tab mode, right side: edit mode.

Maybe you guys have an idea what I can do.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNjE2EVYSq0) help?

Comment: I watched this already. But he is morphing from one image into the other. I need an average face of both image.

Comment: In the tutorial he is playing an animation, at 12:00. Around 12:02 the animation is halfway and shows a blend of the two faces. How is the average you want different from that?

Comment: Yes you right, but i am trying without a video. I don't know if it is possible to create such an average face image. I haven't found until now other tutorials.